# What kind of encoding is this?

Tags: encoding

```
MV5BMTIy*****MTk3NDcyMQ@@._V1._SX96_SY140_.jpg
```

etc etc? I think these are urls encoded ... but I'm not sure.

IMDB uses something like this but I need to know for another site which is ripping someone off and I don't know who.

Comment: It could be a completely randomly generated string. Why do you need to know?

Comment: a site is using another site for providing content while not providing credit. i want to find out what where and why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it could be split up as follows (periods removed):

`MV5BMTIy` -- primary identifier, possibly base-64 encoded, maybe the movie ID

`***` -- unknown suffix

`MTk3NDcy` -- secondary identifier, possibly base-64 encoded

`MQ@@` -- third identifier, possibly base-64 encoded

`_V1` -- version one

`_SX96_` -- 96 pixels wide

`SY140_` -- 140 pixels tall

`jpg` -- JPEG encoded picture

Look at the source of an IMDB page, such as [www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/).  You can see image files related to a particular movie, and the movie-related image file names start with the same prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it is in IMDB format and the site in question fetches the images from IMDB.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like some private format. URL encodings usually have %xx where spaces used to be..